# Value is captured in a closure warning in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, casting, warnings

In the following code snippet, I get the warning `Value is captured in a closure` | `Smart cast to android.os.Bundle`. I haven't been able to figure-out (or find by search) how to do that. Any ideas?

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        chart = savedInstanceState.getInt(CHART_KEY)
    }
    ...
}
```

[image]

Comment: There is no closure shown in your code above. Maybe you accidentally snipped off the relevant part?

Comment: As Tenfour04 says, the question doesn't include all the relevant code, so we can't say very much. But note that ‘Value is captured in a closure’ is only a warning, not an error, and may not be a problem for you; while ‘Smart cast to android.os.Bundle’ is a separate messages, purely for information.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention “smart cast” is not a warning. That’s just the IDE providing helpful info. In this case it’s saying that inside this if statement, the compiler is treating your bundle as non-nullable since you already checked if it was null. That’s a good thing, and the intended way to use Kotlin. I don’t think “value captured in a closure” is a warning either. It’s just the IDE informing you that the compiler is creating a non-local version of a local variable under the hood since it is going to be used in a closure (code that escapes this function such as in a listener).

Comment: Ah. Thanks @Tenfor04 and @gidds! I mistook it as a warning, it's just info from the IDE when I hover over it. I also mistook "Smart cast to android.os.Bundle" as a suggestion instead of an informitive statement from the IDE.